# Trying to find missing switch for outdoor light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I'm currently in the process of trying to figure out which switch in my house turns on an outdoor light fixture. Apparently this switch doesn't exist. The bulb is new, known to be working, and of the appropriate wattage. This fixture has never been on since I bought the house (which isn't all that long ago anyway).

The only thing that I can't explain is that there is a blank face plate opposite the wall shared by this light. Inside are 2 capped wires (shown below). I don't have the slightest clue what these were for, if anything. They were like this when I bought the house.

Could these be from an old switch? Is there a safe way to test them without shorting something? It's probably just a red herring to distract me from my search, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask about anyway. It's not very far from the fixture, so I didn't want to discount the possibility.

[image: wires behind face plate]

If these either are definitely not for a switch, or do not control the outside light, are there any tricks/tips I could attempt in terms of finding where my mystery switch is located?

Here is the box of the fixture outside:
[image: outdoor fixture box]

Comment: Check with volt meter to see if the wires are a hot and a neutral.  Inside the 3 gang box is there evidence that additional wires were run to thus box in the past?

Comment: @Kris - Yup, one hot, one neutral. As far as I can see though, no, there is no evidence of additional wires. Seems like it's just these 2.

Comment: Is the outside fixture easy to remove to get a look at the wires in side the box at that location?

Comment: If 2 wires that is a switch leg if completely wired in the white would be always hot and the black the switches hot that is if it was completed and done to code, it may be disconnected because of a problem with the wires going outside we really don’t know but that would be my guess since that type wire has not been used since the 60’s

Comment: @EdBeal house is from the 20's, so that's fair game :)

Comment: @Kris - easy enough I suppose. Edited picture into post. Not a great image, but the best I can do while one-handed, up on a step ladder :)

Comment: With lighting and switches use caution with colors white is quite often a hot. This just recently changed where a neutral is needed at 1 switch location so the hot white will become very rare with new construction because 12.2.2 is really expensive and smurf tube is cheap, so you run the size and colors you need. I said white always hot in a switch leg it is supposed to be the hot in a 2 wire connection.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the light bulb is good.

Measure voltage across those 2 wires.  Does it read full line voltage?

Remove all the light bulbs. Does the voltage change?  (It might be "phantom voltage").

If the voltage is there with the bulb in, and gone/diminished to phantom when the bulb is out, then it probably is a switch to the bulb.   The next test is to connect those 2 wires to a receptacle, and plug a lamp into the receptacle. (really works best if the lamp has a switch).  Now put same-size incandescent light bulbs in both lamps.

Does turning the temporary lamp on cause the other one to light up?  If yes, are they both about half brightness?  If so, that settles it; that's a switch to that light.

Answer (score 1):

The switch is a switch leg , connect a switch to the 2 wires and it will provide the power to the fixture, use caution because with switches prior to the last code change it is quite common to have a switch leg and the white is always hot, the black is the switched hot, it is this way so you don’t think the white is a neutral. Since there were 2 wires only in the box where the switch was or should be located and multiple at the light fixture this your best first choice.

Edit closer inspection of your fixture location , the prior owners may have disconnected the switch leg I see bare copper. If the switch is not connected the proper method would be to connect that white to the always hot in the box (coming from the breaker or fuse panel) mark that white black at both ends.
Connect your other black to the fixture light black.
The fixture white goes to the neutral feeder the white that comes in the box with the always hot That is the neutral there may be several wire Nutted together. That would be the proper way to connect your light and switch.

Comment: With a set up like this the wires were ran to the fixture first, then the2 wires like we see in the box One went from hot at fixture to the switch and the other from switch back to fixture providing a current interruption device correct?

Comment: Yes very common to run the hot as short as possible.